# Retrieving parameters infors of stored procedure in Java / Oracle

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc

i hit following problem when migrating oracle 9i to 11g: the parameters's infors of stored procedure retrieved by DatabaseMetaData sont wrong with oracle 11g

here is my test

**oracle**

```
create or replace procedure prodc_test(
  -- numeric datatypes --
  pparam01 float,        
  pparam02 number,        
  --pparam03 binary_float, not available in 9i --        
  --pparam04 binary_double, not available in 9i --                
  -- character datatypes --
  pparam20 char, 
  pparam21 in varchar, 
  pparam22 in out varchar2, 
  pparam23 out nchar, 
  pparam24 nvarchar2,
  pparam25 long,
  -- date datatype -- 
  pparam30 date,        
  pparam31 timestamp,
  pparam32 timestamp with time zone,
  pparam34 timestamp with local time zone,
  -- lob datatypes --
  pparam40 blob,
  pparam41 clob,
  pparam42 nclob,
  pparam43 bfile,
  -- raw and long raw datatypes --
  pparam50 raw,
  pparam51 long raw,
  -- rowid and urowid datatypes --
  pparam60 rowid,
  pparam61 urowid
) as 
begin
     --null;
     pparam22 := 'test22';
     pparam23 := 'test23';
end;
/
```

**java**

```
DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = dbConn.getMetaData();
LOGGER.debug("DB DriverVersionn ={}", dbMetaData.getDriverVersion());
LOGGER.debug("DB Product Name   ={}", dbMetaData.getDatabaseProductName());
LOGGER.debug("DB Product Version={}", dbMetaData.getDatabaseProductVersion());
LOGGER.debug("DB Driver Name    ={}", dbMetaData.getDriverName());
LOGGER.debug("DB Driver Version ={}", dbMetaData.getDriverVersion());
LOGGER.debug("DB Username       ={}", dbMetaData.getUserName());
LOGGER.debug("DB URL            ={}", dbMetaData.getURL());

String procedure = "PRODC_TEST";
ResultSet tSchema = dbMetaData.getProcedureColumns(null, null, procedure, null);
while (tSchema.next()) {
    String fieldName = tSchema.getString("COLUMN_NAME").substring(1);
    LOGGER.debug("getProcedureParameters({}), COLUMN_NAME:{}, COLUMN_TYPE:{}, DATA_TYPE:{}, TYPE_NAME:{}", procedure, fieldName,
            tSchema.getInt("COLUMN_TYPE"), tSchema.getString("DATA_TYPE"), tSchema.getString("TYPE_NAME"));
    }
}
tSchema.close();
```

with oracle 9i, output is

```
DB DriverVersionn =11.2.0.3.0
DB Product Name   =Oracle
DB Product Version=Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options JServer Release 9.2.0.4.0 - Production
DB Driver Name    =Oracle JDBC driver
DB Driver Version =11.2.0.3.0
DB Username       =SCHEMA_USER
DB URL            =jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.y.z.t:1521:SID
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM01, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:FLOAT
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM02, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:3, TYPE_NAME:NUMBER
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM20, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:1, TYPE_NAME:CHAR
ggetProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM21, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:12, TYPE_NAME:VARCHAR2
ggetProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM22, COLUMN_TYPE:2, DATA_TYPE:12, TYPE_NAME:VARCHAR2
ggetProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM23, COLUMN_TYPE:4, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:NCHAR
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM24, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:NVARCHAR2
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM25, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:-1, TYPE_NAME:LONG
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM30, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:93, TYPE_NAME:DATE
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM31, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:93, TYPE_NAME:TIMESTAMP
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM32, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:-101, TYPE_NAME:TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM34, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:-102, TYPE_NAME:TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM40, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:BLOB
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM41, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:CLOB
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM42, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:NCLOB
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM43, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:BFILE
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM50, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:-3, TYPE_NAME:RAW
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM51, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:-4, TYPE_NAME:LONG RAW
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM60, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:ROWID
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM61, COLUMN_TYPE:1, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:UROWID
```

with oracle 11g, output is

```
DB DriverVersionn =11.2.0.3.0
DB Product Name   =Oracle
DB Product Version=Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
DB Driver Name    =Oracle JDBC driver
DB Driver Version =11.2.0.3.0
DB Username       =SCHEMA_USER
DB URL            =jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.y.z.t2:1521:SID
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM01, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:float
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM02, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:number
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM03, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:binary_float
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM04, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:binary_double
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM20, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:char
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM21, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:varchar2
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM22, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:varchar2
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM23, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:nchar
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM24, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:nvarchar2
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM25, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:long
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM30, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:date
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM31, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:timestamp
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM32, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:timestamp with time zone
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM34, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:timestamp with local time zone
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM40, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:blob
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM41, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:clob
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM42, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:nclob
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM43, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:bfile
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM50, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:raw
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM51, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:long raw
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM60, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:rowid
getProcedureParameters(PRODC_TEST), COLUMN_NAME:PARAM61, COLUMN_TYPE:0, DATA_TYPE:1111, TYPE_NAME:urowid
```

=> problem:  COLUMN_TYPE = 0 (java.sql.DatabaseMetaData.procedureColumnUnknown) and DATA_TYPE = 1111 (java.sql.Types.OTHER)

why? is it a bug? solution?
thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of the JDBC driver?

Comment: yes, i have tried the lastest jdbc driver 11.2.0.4.0 => the same problem